# Why does my update function return the new query but not update the database?

Tags: mongodb, rest, go, crud

I am creating a RESTful API and am in the process of creating an update function. I use FindOneAndUpdate, and it doesn't actually update the database.

I have tried many things, but I'm fairly new to the language so I'm a bit lost.

```golang
func UpdateCompanyEndpoint(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    response.Header().Set("content-type", "application/json")
    params := mux.Vars(request)
    name, _ := params["name"]
    var company Company
    _ = json.NewDecoder(request.Body).Decode(&company)
    collection := client.Database("RESTful").Collection("companies")
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    filter := bson.D{{"name", name}}
    update := bson.D{{"$set", bson.D{{"application", company.Application}}}}
    err := collection.FindOneAndUpdate(
        ctx,
        filter,
        update).Decode(&company)
    if err == nil {
        response.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    json.NewEncoder(response).Encode(company)
}
```

```
[
    {
        "name": "Test1",
        "application": "Test1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Test2",
        "application": "Test2"
    },
    {
        "name": "Test3",
        "application": "Test3"
    }
]
```

This is the current database. When I call the function, it returns:

```
{
    "name": "Test2",
    "application": "Test2update"
}
```

but the database remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this block:

```golang
if err == nil {
    response.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
json.NewEncoder(response).Encode(company)
```

Notice carefully, you are sending `StatusInternalServerError` is `err` is `nil`, and you get the response you posted when `err != nil`, so some error is occuring in your case.

Comment: Doesn't my FindOneAndUpdate function return the new and updated data, so there is no error if err == nil?

Comment: But why are you returning Internal Server Error if err == nil?

Comment: Ok, so I got rid of the error handling for now to try and make the code work. It still does not work. Maybe the issue is within my filter or update? Or is it in my FindOneAndUpdate?

Comment: try to log `err`

Comment: I see many examples online on github where they do not handle the error.

Comment: I would not recommend that though